# Azure multiple VM connect to the same HD?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

**I need to share the same hard disk with multiple Cloud-Services/VM, does it possible ?**

If it possible how can I do it ?

I know that I can use storage like Blob Storage or SQL to store data but I'm using a local software on each service that only accepts local paths to import data (to it).

Comment: Try this, which allows you to share a vhd as a network drive across multiple VM's or locally or across different networks - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620645/shared-drive-between-azure-virtual-machines/40326408#40326408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can share the exact same HD, but Azure File Service may be helpful.

Here's a link [for more details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx)
And a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620645/shared-drive-between-azure-virtual-machines) post that may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible in general.

However you can mount the VHD and then create a UNC path to it, and that file path can be shared. However, at this point, it is more useful to just use Azure File Services (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx).

Comment: Yes, creating a share in Azure File Service and mounting the share to your multiple VMs as local drive letters is the best solution for your scenario.