# network share in vmscale set accessible for a service running under network service account

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, network-share

I have a network shared folder in one of the VMs which needs to be accessible by other VMs in the same VM scale set. The service would be running under network service account.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to avoid using a VM disk to others in scalesets as this will be a SPOF.
You can use azure file share in a storage account and then you need to run a powershell as script extension to mount the network share on each new vm.
You can find the command example in here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-disk-ps

Comment: We are not worried about SPOF for this service since latency is more important. Due to this the network shared folder needs to be accessible by each vm in the scale set by a service running under network service account

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620645/shared-drive-between-azure-virtual-machines